# Partition Errors and Remounts Read-Only when Accessing Specific File

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ext4, badblocks

I have a pretty basic system running Ubuntu 16.04, 1 HDD, running a few partitions:

```
sda1 - EXT4 - 100G   - /
sda2 - EXT4 - 723.5G - /home
sda3 - NTFS - 100G   - (windows)
sda5 - SWAP - 8G
```

Whenever I try to access one of 3-4 files in a specific directory in the `/home` partition, (the specific folder causing the issues is `/home/path/to/broken/folder`), the `/home` partition will error and remount read-only. `dmesg` shows the following errors:

```
EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_ext_check_inode:497: inode #1415: comm rm: pblk 0 bad header/extent: invalid magic - magic 0, entries 0, max 0(0), depth 0(0)
Aborting journal on device sda2-8.
EXT4-fs (sda2): Remounting filesystem read-only
EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_ext_check_inode:497: inode #1417: comm rm: pblk 0 bad header/extent: invalid magic - magic 0, entries 0, max 0(0), depth 0(0)
EXT4-fs error (device sda2): ext4_ext_check_inode:497: inode #1416: comm rm: pblk 0 bad header/extent: invalid magic - magic 0, entries 0, max 0(0), depth 0(0)
```

So I understand what is going on...some bad block is causing an error and is remounting the drive read-only to prevent further corruption. I know it is these specific files because I can undo the error by

1. Logging in as root
2. Running `sync`
3. Stopping `lightdm` (and all sub-processes)
4. Stop all remaining open files on `/home` by finding them with `lsof | grep /home`
5. Unmounting `/home`
6. Running `fsck /home` (fixing the errors)
7. Remount `/home`

Everything is fine again, read and write, *until I try to access the same files again*, then this entire process is repeated to fix it again.

The way I've tried to access the files is by running `ls /home/path/to/broken/folder` and `rm -r /home/path/to/broken/folder`, so it seems any kind of HDD operation on that part of the drive errors it and throws it into read-only again.

I honestly don't care about the files, I just want them gone. I am willing to remove the entire `/home/path/to/broken/folder` folder, but every time I try this, it fails and throws into read-only.

How can I fix this without re-formatting the entire `/home` drive?

---

**EDIT 1:**

I ran `badblocks -v /dev/sda2` on my hard drive, but it came out clean, no bad blocks. Any help would still be greatly appreciated.

---

**EDIT 2:**

Still looking for a solution to this. Some information that might be useful below:

```
$ debugfs -R 'stat <1415>' /dev/sda2
debugfs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Inode: 1415   Type: regular    Mode:  0644   Flags:  0x80000
Generation: 0    Version: 0x00000000
User:     0   Group:     0   Size: 0
File ACL: 0    Directory ACL: 0
Links: 1   Blockcount: 0
Fragment:  Address: 0    Number: 0    Size: 0
ctime: 0x5639ad86 -- Wed Nov  4 01:02:30 2015
atime: 0x5639ad86 -- Wed Nov  4 01:02:30 2015
mtime: 0x5639ad86 -- Wed Nov  4 01:02:30 2015
Size of extra inode fields: 0
EXTENTS:
```

Now I looked at this myself and compared it to what I suspect to be a non-corrupted inode:

```
$ debugfs -R 'stat <1410>' /dev/sda2
debugfs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Inode: 1410   Type: regular    Mode:  0644   Flags:  0x80000
Generation: 0    Version: 0x00000000
User:     0   Group:     0   Size: 996
File ACL: 0    Directory ACL: 0
Links: 1   Blockcount: 0
Fragment:  Address: 0    Number: 0    Size: 0
ctime: 0x5639ad31 -- Wed Nov  4 01:01:05 2015
atime: 0x5639ad31 -- Wed Nov  4 01:01:05 2015
mtime: 0x5639ad31 -- Wed Nov  4 01:01:05 2015
Size of extra inode fields: 0
EXTENTS:
(0):46679378
```

I have bolded what I believe are the key differences here. I looked at other non-corrupted inodes and they display something similar to the `1410` that has a non-zero size and an extent.

Bad header/extent makes sense here...it has no extent....how do I fix this?

<sub>I really feel like I've handed this question to someone smarter than me on a silver platter, I just don't know what the meal (answer) is!</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer from somebody else on another site, just zeroed the inodes and rechecked the system, that was all!

```
debugfs -w /dev/sda2
:clri <1415>
:clri <1416>
:clri <1417>
:q
fsck -y /dev/sda2
```

To anybody else with this issue, I found my bad inodes using `find` on the bad mount, then checked `dmesg` for errors on the bad inodes.